# Setting compiler args as list of string in new language plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I’m developing a plugin for a new language and I was trying to add support for compile options to the compiler. I’ve used the `org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions` class as a starting point and implemented my own class as following:

```
class SvCompileOptions extends AbstractOptions {
    private List<String> compilerArgs = Lists.newArrayList();

    @Input
    public List<String> getCompilerArgs() {
        return compilerArgs;
    }

    public void setCompilerArgs(List<String> compilerArgs) {
        this.compilerArgs = compilerArgs;
    }
}
```

In my build.gradle file, I’ve tried doing the following:

```
compileSv {
    options.compilerArgs += [ "-foo" ]
}
```

(compileSv is a task with an options property of type SvCompileOptions.)

I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':uvc2'.
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)
```

If I replace the line with:

```
compileSv {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-foo")
}
```

then everything works fine, but it’s not very gradlesque.

Can someone please point out what I’m doing wrong?

---

As per @tim_yates' suggestion, I've added a function to append to the `compilerArgs`:

```
class SvCompileOptions extends AbstractOptions {

    void compilerArgs(String... args) {
        this.compilerArgs.addAll(args as List)
    }
}
```

---

As per @Opal's suggestion, I've created a barebones example:

```
// File 'build.gradle'

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:16+'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;


class SvCompileOptions extends AbstractOptions {

    private List<String> compilerArgs = Lists.newArrayList();

    @Input
    public List<String> getCompilerArgs() {
        return compilerArgs;
    }

    public void setCompilerArgs(List<String> compilerArgs) {
        this.compilerArgs = compilerArgs;
    }

    void compilerArgs(String... args) {
        this.compilerArgs.addAll(args as List)
    }

}


class SvCompile extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    protected void compile() {
        println options.compilerArgs
    }

    @Nested
    SvCompileOptions options = new SvCompileOptions()

}


task compileSv(type: SvCompile)


compileSv {
    options.compilerArgs 'foo', 'bar'
}
```

The code appends the arguments to the empty list and prints `[foo, bar]` as expected. If we try to overwrite the arguments using the following:

```
compileSv {
    options.compilerArgs = ['one', 'two']
}
```

an error message is printed:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'so_compile_options2'.
> SvCompileOptions.setProperty(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

I'm not sure why the error message is different when the classes are inlined in `build.gradle`, but I would assume this is what leads to the `AbstractMethodError` I was seeing.

As @Opal pointed out, this problem is caused by some magic being done inside the `AbstractOptions` class. I tried adding the following methods to the compile options class, but the error message is still there:

```
class SvCompileOptions extends AbstractOptions {

    private static final ImmutableSet<String> EXCLUDE_FROM_ANT_PROPERTIES =
            ImmutableSet.of("compilerArgs");

    @Override
    protected boolean excludeFromAntProperties(String fieldName) {
        return EXCLUDE_FROM_ANT_PROPERTIES.contains(fieldName);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The exclude function doesn't seem to be called at all, as if I add a dummy print inside it it never gets issued.

Comment: Could you please provide a SSCCE? And run the script with `-s` switch?

Comment: If you don't extend `AbstractOptions` it works as expected so I guess this class introduces some _magic_ - can't help you further right now - have to do my own job.

Comment: @Opal Thanks for the hint regarding `AbstractOptions`. What does SSCCE mean?

Comment: It's just a working example: http://sscce.org/ :)

Comment: @Opal I regretted not providing an example, but I didn't have the code/infrastructure available when I posted the question. I hoped it's an easy issue that an experienced Gradle user could spot instantly. I'll update the question later.

Comment: @Opal I'm assuming the issue has something to do with the whole `optionMap()` mechanism. Not sure what that's supposed to do, though.

Comment: Yes, I thought exactly the same but had no time to check.

Comment: The following issue on the Gradle Github page says that they're planning to remove the `AbstractOptions` class completely: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the valuable insight from @Opal that extending from `AbstractOptions` is the source of the problem and finding an issue on the Gradle Github page related to [removing the `AbstractOptions` class altogether](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3026), I think the best thing to do is to just not use a base class at all.

After integrating @tim_yates' suggestion for the 'append' method, I'll go with the following implementation:

```
class SvCompileOptions {

    private List<String> compilerArgs = Lists.newArrayList();

    @Input
    public List<String> getCompilerArgs() {
        return compilerArgs;
    }

    // Overwrites
    public void setCompilerArgs(List<String> compilerArgs) {
        this.compilerArgs = compilerArgs;
    }

    // Appends
    void compilerArgs(String... args) {
        this.compilerArgs.addAll(args as List)
    }

}
```

This allows the user to append arguments:

```
compileSv {
    options.compilerArgs 'foo', 'bar'
}
```

and to overwrite them:

```
compileSv {
    options.compilerArgs = ['one', 'two']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
options.compilerArgs << "-foo"
```

An idiomatic way of doing this if you want to add multiple values (which you probably will do at some point) is to change your class to:

```
class SvCompileOptions extends AbstractOptions {
    @Input
    List<String> compilerArgs = Lists.newArrayList();

    def args(String... args) {
        this.compilerArgs += args.toList()
    }
}
```

Then, you can do:

```
compileSv {
    options.args "-foo", "-bar"
}
```

Comment: That's true. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll also add something like this. This still doesn't explain the error, though.

Comment: Despite it works Tim, it rather looks like a workaround.

Comment: @TudorTimi does it work if you just remove the getter and setter and annotate the field instead?

Comment: @tim_yates What do you mean by annotating the field? (newbie question)

Comment: Put the annotation on the field, instead of annotating the method (as in my response) if you remove `private` you can just delete the getter and setter methods, as groovy generates them for you

Comment: Interesting. I'll keep this in mind. I've kind of given up on the `AbstractOptions` thing, since it's marked for deprecation. I'll try it with the field annotation, though. I noticed I've been writing Java-style code in Groovy and this might somehow lead to the error. Dunno what other magic Groovy might do.